# How to remove fields using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to increase the number of fields by clicking the add more button and I am successful in doing that. But, I don't understand where I am going wrong. It shows up the alert but won't remove the field any help is appreciated.

**Jquery:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=0;
    $('#addmore').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#Files").append("<input name='file' id='file"+x+"' type='file'/><br>");
        $("#rem").append("<input  value='remove' id='but"+x+"' type='button'/><br>");
        $("#but"+x).click(function(){
                alert("#but"+x);
                $("#but"+x,"#file"+x).remove();
        });

      x++;
    });

});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div>
<form name="imageForm" id="imageForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imageuploadlogic.jsp">
<input type="file" name="file0" id="imagefile" class=""/><br>
<div id="Files" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="rem" style="float: left;"></div><br>
<input type="button" id="addmore" value="addmore"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitimage" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a shared variable `x`, the removal logic won't be proper try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 0;
    $('#addmore').click(function (e) {
        var id = x;
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#Files").append("<input name='file' id='file" + id + "' type='file'/><br>");
        $("#rem").append("<input  value='remove' id='but" + id + "' type='button'/><br>");
        $("#but" + x).click(function () {
            $("#file" + id).add(this).remove();
        });

        x++;
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tBNpY/)

But I would recommend a event delegation based solution like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 0;
    $('#addmore').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#Files").append("<input name='file' id='file" + x + "' type='file'/><br>");
        $("#rem").append("<input  value='remove' id='but" + x + "' data-id='" + x + "' type='button'/><br>");

        x++;
    });
    $("#rem").on('click', 'input[value="remove"]', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $("#file" + id).add(this).remove();
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tBNpY/2/)

Comment: can you please mention the advantage of the 2nd solution.

Comment: Arun don't forget the extra `<br>` left behind after removing the elements and the input names are all gonna be the same (maybe make into array `name='file[]'`)